# Python manage.py runserver not responding

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am new to Python and trying to execute "python manage.py runserver" from the command line shell but nothing happens and it just goes to the next line without any error message. It was working fine earlier, and I realize that after I installed vcruntime140.dll and restarted the computer it stopped working. Please help

Comment: Hello Vijay, welcome on Stack Overflow. What do you mean by "stopped working"? What is the error? Also, having the code for `manage.py` would help understand your issue.

Comment: Have you created a Django App? Can you chcek in your browser if it's runing when you execute runserver?

Comment: Hello amiabl and Houda, thanks for responding. By stopped working I meant that it was working from the command line earlier, however after i installed vcruntime140.dll and restarted my computer it stopped working. The browser displays "site can't be reached". However, I figured out the issue, it was windows blocking it, I followed the below instructions given in the forum and it worked for me "You can disable the shortcuts without installing Python by opening "Manage app execution aliases" from Start, finding the "App Installer" Python entries and switching them to "Off".